# Remove text from String via Regexp

Tags: java, regex

in Java I want to remove some text from the following String via Regexp:

```
someText

begin
  .someMethod()
  .doSomething(TOKEN_123)
  .someMethod()
end

begin
  .someMethod()
  .doSomething(TOKEN_456)
  .someMethod()
end

begin
  .someMethod()
  .doSomething(TOKEN_789)
  .someMethod()
end

more Text
```

I want to remove the 2nd begin/end-Block which includes the String TOKEN_456.

Currently my regexp looks like the following

```
begin.*TOKEN_456(.*?)end
```

but this one removes the first AND second block.

Can anyone help please?

Greetz

Comment: I guess you have the singleline flag. Why not split by multiple newlines and remove the element of the resulting array, and then joining the rest? BTW, you are looking for `begin(?:(?!begin).)*TOKEN_456(.*?)end`.

Comment: @tripleee: Not this one for sure.

Comment: As I mentioned, the dupe was absolutely incorrect, it is not solved with negated character class or lazy dot matching, thus relieved the close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
str = str.replaceFirst("(?s)begin(?:(?!begin).)*TOKEN_456.*?end\\s*", ""));
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/pzs9ZS) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vN5vT7/4).

The regex matches:

- `(?s)` - a singleline modifier
- `begin` - matches the leading boundary, a character sequence `begin`
- `(?:(?!begin).)*` - a tempered greedy token that matches any text that is not starting the word `begin`
- `TOKEN_456` - a literal character sequence to match
- `.*?end` - any number of any characters as few as possible, up to the closest `end`
- `\\s*` - 0 or more whitespace (for trimming purposes).

Comment: You can improve performance of the regex if you add more "anchoring" details, like word boundaries, start of *line* anchor, newlines: [`"(?sm)^begin\\b(?:(?!\\bbegin\\b).)*TOKEN_456(.*?)\nend(?:$|\n)"`](https://regex101.com/r/vN5vT7/2).

Comment: Just noticed a capturing group on `(.*?)` - I guess you can remove the parentheses if you are not interested in the captured text.

Comment: ah good to know. Thought I always have to use brackets in this context